# Is that correct. Can we use sentense THE use like this

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

We have forwarded **the** hard copy of **the** document; kindly confirm to us once you receive the document

Please advise the correct grammatical sentence

Comment: Please indicate your research.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be:

> We have forwarded **a** hard copy of **the** document. Kindly confirm to us once you receive the document.

"*a* hard copy" because there can be any number of copies (logically).

"*the* document" because there is only one original document (being singular).

Comment: But if there is only one hard copy, *the hard copy* is fine. In fact, if there are more than one hard copies, *the hard copy* is also fine if it refers to the one hard copy that the writer assumes his reader can identify, either by past reference or shared knowledge.